# How overwrite product price in plugin but not taking the cached price?

Tags: frontend, cache, plugin, product-prices, custom-prices

I have a plugin to change the product price, but when the plugin is called again, it's render the cache product price in the frontend. Any way to take the plugin info instead of the cache?

This is my etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
    <plugin name="Vendor_Module_Plugin_Magento_Model_Product" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Product" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

And the plugin:

```
public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
{                               
    $result = $this->helper->calculatePrice($subject->getId());        
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Sorry just deleted my answer, didn't read the question properly ! Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Thanks anyway!!

Comment: what is the problem with cache? Is the price value different between cache and non-cached version?

Comment: Hi, yes, the price loaded dynamically.